# How to build OR logic in solr-node-client

Tags: solr

All:

I wonder how to build search query like `field:"key word 1" OR field:"key word 2"` with solr-node-client?

There is example page : 
http://lbdremy.github.io/solr-node-client/code/search.js.html

But I did not find any example to solve my question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the official [github](https://github.com/lbdremy/solr-node-client/pull/19) of `solr-node-client`:

```
var query = client.createQuery().q('(key1:value1 AND key2:value2) OR key1:value3');
```

Comment: thanks, so there is no way to pass an Object to specify the logic? Like `{ "OR": [{field:value}, {field: value}]}`